# Re-enable delete confirmation in Sticky Notes in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, sticky-notes

Sticky Notes in Windows 10 asks you if you're sure before deleting a sticky note. Unfortunately I disabled this feature by accident. How do I re-enable it?

Comment: If you're running v1511 or earlier per chance, instructions [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/971605) should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is encompassed within the `File Explorer` delete confirmation, I configure it within the `Local Group Policy editor` on my Windows 10 Pro machines:

1. Click on the `Start` button
2. Search for `gpedit.msc`, right-click it and `Run as administrator`
3. Navigate to `User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\File Explorer`
4. Enable `Display confirmation dialog when deleting files`

On the other hand, if you are referring to the capability within Sticky Notes themselves and accidentally checked `Don't show this message again` when it asked if you were sure you wanted to delete the note, there are methods to regain that functionality.

If you are running Windows 10 Version 1607 (a.k.a. the Anniversary Update), you actually need to reset the application:

1. Click on the `Start` button
2. Select `Settings`
3. Select `System`
4. Click on `Apps & features` on the left side
5. Scroll down the right column and select `Sticky Notes`
6. Click on `Advanced Options`

[image: Sticky Notes Advanced Options]

7. Click on the `Reset` button

[image: Sticky Notes Reset Button]

8. You will be queried with a confirmation dialog box and another `Reset` button.  (*please remember that while this will restore the Sticky Notes delete confirmation, **you will lose any data** that isn't already backed-up elsewhere*)

[image: Sticky Notes Reset Confirmation]

Finally, if you are running an older version of Windows 10 prior to 1607 (a.k.a. the Anniversary Update), it requires a relatively simple registry change:

1. Click on the `Start` button
2. Search for `Regedit` and open the Registry Editor
3. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\StickyNotes`
4. Double-click the `PROMPT_ON_DELETE` registry entry
5. In the Value data box, type 1, and click `OK`
6. Exit the Registry Editor

([Source](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/enable-sticky-notes-delete-confirmation-prompt/))

Comment: Doesn't the registry change work with Version 1607 and above?

Comment: @ADTC, the article that I referenced as my source emphasizes that it doesn't. Prior to Windows 10 version 1607, Sticky Notes was a classic desktop program. Beginning with the Anniversary Update, Sticky Notes is now a modern/universal app, instead. As a result, if you check within the registry on a Windows 10 version 1607 (or newer) machine you will see that the 'StickyNotes' key doesn't actually exist